# help with sendmail configuration to send mail through my gmail account?

Tags: windows, sendmail, email, xampp

**This is the sendmail.ini file what to change now**

```
# Example for a user configuration file

# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
logfile "\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.log"

# Mercury
account Mercury
host localhost
from postmaster@localhost
auth off

# A freemail service example
account gmail
tls on
tls_certcheck off
host smtp.gmail.com
from ****@gmail.com
auth on
user ****@gmail.com
password *******

# Set a default account
account default : Mercury
```

Answer (score 1):

Needs to add [port 587] in the config [1](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=37120&start=0&sid=a8c39c25ce85a2dd3e23a728c2d83169&view=print)

```
account Gmail
tls on
port 587
tls_certcheck off
host smtp.gmail.com
from ***@gmail.com
auth on
user ***@gmail.com
password mygmailpassword

# Set a default account
account default : Gmail
```